# Put in the same line a textbox and button

Tags: jquery-mobile, button, textbox, inline

(jQuery Mobile): I'm trying to put in the same line my textbox and search button but i really don't know how. I google it how to, but the solutions really doesn't work for me.

I have this HTML code for it:

```
<div id="search">
   <form id="search_form" method="GET">
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" data-inline="true"/>
     <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" data-inline="true" />
   </form>
</div>
```

[image]

Thank your for answers.

Comment: You can use `ui-grid` http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/rfqSk/ with a little bit of css customisation. http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/grids/